# infer table structure from file in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Another posting said there is a way to infer the table columns from a data file using phpMyAdmin.  I haven't found documentation on this, can you point me to it?  Does it only use the header row, or does it also sample the data to infer the data type?

I'm trying to create several tables in MySQL from data files, which have roughly 100 columns each, so I don't want to write the SQL DDL to create the tables manually.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `data file`? What type of file? is it a `.frm` file?